# SSI и кэширование nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, ssi

Есть `HTML` страничка, которую нужно закешировать,и в ней кусок `PHP` кода, который кэшировать не нужно. Делаю это все при помощи `SSI`.

```
location ~ \.(php|html)$ {
            ssi on;
            try_files  $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME 
            $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
            fastcgi_cache MYCACHE; 
            fastcgi_cache_valid 200 4h;
```

В html вывожу так `<!--# include virtual="/file.php" -->`

При вЫключенном кэшировании `fastcgi_cache off;` все работает, но если я его включаю получаю ошибку:

> an error occurred while processing the directive

Подскажите, какое-нибудь рабочее решение.

Comment: Не включать кеширование :)  смысл кеша то в кешировинии объектов, или провести тюнинг условий кеширования, например не кешировать файлы с расширением .SHTML в которых и подключать инклюды.

Comment: Включите отладочные логи: `error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;    log_subrequest  on;` - что там выведется?

Comment: @sanmai [ссылка](https://dropmefiles.com/floZF) длинный error log, залил на ФО

Comment: gist.github.com чем не подходит? файлы качать - это боль

Comment: Прошу прощения. Я не в курсе о такой штуке) [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/beneran55/7fa04a12e34860847da6f1643bd55da2)